# svg hover working in ff and chrome no go in IE 9 10 11

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

[edit] I apologize this is my first time asking for assistance here. The code didn't paste properly initially so here is the link to the jsfiddle I created which was requested in the comments, https://jsfiddle.net/silvioj/0gp6rL3u/, Thanks again![edit](if you hover over the blank looking button you'll see the effect.)

Full code attached below. Basically I've tried it a couple different ways and it seemed to be working well until I tested it in IE. Basically I have a circle menu I generated with an online tool. With the circle in the center I'm planning to change the fill image on button hover.

The below code is a duplicate of what I think might be the issue. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but IE 9 10 11 is a no go.

Please help, this is my first experiment with svg for a client of mine.

Thanks in advance!

```
    <pattern id="image2" x="0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="http://ewi.silviotech.com/wp-content/themes/ExhibitWorks2015/images/logomain_01.png">
  <set attributeName="xlink:href" to="http://silviotech.com/wp-content/themes/SilvioTech2015/images/logol.png" begin="item12.mouseover" end="item12.mouseout"/> </image>   
   </pattern>
```

```
<!-- SVG Menu Generated By CIRCULUS.SVG :: http://sarasoueidan.com/tools/circulus -->
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-2 -2 504 504" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" id="menu" style="transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); touch-action: none; -webkit-user-select: none;width: 100%; padding-bottom: 100%; height: 1px; overflow: visible">
                <style>
                    #menu {
                        display: block;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                        /*overflow: visible;*/ /* uncomment this if you are using bouncing animations*/
                    }

                    a { 
                        cursor: pointer; 
                        outline: none;
                    }

                    /* You can change these default styles any way you want */

                    .item .sector {
                        transition: all .1s linear;
                        fill: #fff;
                        stroke: #111;
                    }


                    .item:hover .sector, .item:focus .sector {
                        fill: #eee;
                    }

                    .menu-trigger {
                        fill: #EA2A55;
                        pointer-events: auto; 
                    }

                    .menu-trigger:hover, .menu-trigger:focus {
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                    symbol {
                        overflow: visible; /* KEEP THIS so that text will not get cut off it it is wider than the icon width */
                    }
                    #circwind
                    {
                    background:#fff;

                    }

            </style>
                <g id="symbolsContainer">    <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-1" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">1</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-2" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">2</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-3" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">3</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-4" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">4</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-5" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">5</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-6" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">6</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-7" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">7</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-8" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">8</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-9" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">9</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-10" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">10</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-11" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">11</text></symbol>

<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-12" viewBox="0 0 37 37"><!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon--><rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect><text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">12</text></symbol>
```

```
    <pattern id="image2" x="0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="http://silviotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/logor1.png">
  <set attributeName="xlink:href" to="http://silviotech.com/wp-content/themes/SilvioTech2015/images/logol.png" begin="item12.mouseover" end="item12.mouseout"/> </image>   
   </pattern>
```

```
                    </circle>

                <!-- menu button label or icon goes here -->

            </svg>
```

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle, it will be easier to edit and test

Comment: Sorry the code didnt copy properly when i pasted it as this is the first time im asking for help here. Also i realize the images arent sized properly i just threw a couple links to images of sites i own...  https://jsfiddle.net/silvioj/0gp6rL3u/  jsfiddle working in ff, chrome but not ie any version. (if you hover over the blank looking button you'll see the effect.)

Comment: IE does not support SMIL. You can use https://leunen.me/fakesmile/ to polyfill suppport though.

Comment: thank you, i implemented this fix this morning. I did  a bit of research into smil too, surprising that no ie supports any bit of it yet. After reading up on fakesmile, it seems for my solutions it should be a perfect solution, i'm not doing anything too elaborate and it seems to provide support for the older browser so i don't have to worry. thanks again!